# How to fit R histogram within axes limits [0,1]

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I generate data using `x <- rnorm(10000)` and then plot a simple histogram using `hist(x)`.

This obviously shows that the data is normal, but the `x` and `y` axes are determined by the values generated.  How could I adjust `x` so that the histogram will still appear as a normal curve, but on a plot whose bounds are `x=[0,1]` and `y=[0,1]`. I tried using this normalization method from another answer, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range, and setting `xlim` and `ylim` to `c(0,1)`, but the result was not what I wanted, as it basically just fills up the entire plot.

Comment: There is an argument in the `hist` function that called `prob`; set it to `TRUE` and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If you're setting the `ylim` to `c(0,1)` in your frequency plot that's the reason why its taking up the whole screen - because everything has a frequency > 1. You should normalize it so that the x-axis is on `c(0,1)` and then you can use the `prob` option in `hist` per @Abdou's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'fills up the whole plot'.  This code seems to work fine:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
z <- (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
hist(z)
```

Then if you want the y-axis on a scale of 0-1:

```
hist1 <- hist(z)
hist1$counts <- hist1$counts/sum(hist1$counts)
plot(hist1, ylim = c(0,1)) ## Looks squished to me if you include the ylim argument
```

Comment: While this accomplishes the goals of question, it is a pretty weird thing to do since you can't untransform the data without knowing the max and min from the original transformation (it isn't like log transforming where you can just apply a function and go back to the original scale). I'm not saying there is a less weird way to do it... I'm more saying, it's a weird thing to ask.